# How can I rename a module using VBA macro?

Tags: vba, excel, vbe

I put one button on sheet. I want to assign macro for that button which change the module name.

For e.g. There are two modules named `Module1` and `Module2`. So I want to replace module name of above two modules with each other. Can anyone suggest me how to rename a module using macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can program *Visual Basic Editor (VBE)*  (actually it is funny I just answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48090077/2685412) awhile ago).
 Check it out to see how to add reference to *VBA Extensibility Library*.
 Something like below should work for you once you've properly set up the required reference:

```
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject, wb as Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set VBProj = wb.VBProject
VBProj.VBComponents("Module1").Name = "Module2"
```

**Important:**

1. Add reference to *VBA Extensibility Library*

   > Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3
2. Tick *Trust access to the VBA project object model* under *Developer Macro Settings*.
   [image: screen shot]
3. Project should be unlocked.